# Hyperledger Fabric Help? ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm having issue running a test channel setup for hyperledger fabric setup. I'm following the docz, but the setup isn't working:

```
docker exec cli peer channel create -c mychannel \
> -f /opt/home/mychannel.pb -o $ORDERER \
> --cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls
```

The output in therminal is this:

```
[main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /opt/home/admin-msp: administrators must be declared when no admin ou classification is set
```

Has anyone seen this error before or know if this is a Docker file issue?